# Parse big JSON Data info HTML Table

Tags: javascript, html, json

I want to implement the JSON File into an HTML Table. In my case it doesnt work however. The table should show all data at once (if possible)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Make a table based on JSON data.</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var obj, dbParam, xmlhttp, myObj, x, txt = "";
obj = { table: "name", limit: 50 };
dbParam = JSON.stringify(obj);
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    myObj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    txt += "<table border='1'>"
    for (x in myObj) {
      txt += "<tr><td>" + myObj[x].name + "</td></tr>";
    }

    txt += "</table>"    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = txt;
  }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://infoportal.vag.de/InfoPortal/busstations.xhr", true);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send("x=" + dbParam);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Are there errors? Is the page blank? Did the response come back with data?

Comment: it's a Cross-Origin Request problem, the size of the table has nothing to do

Comment: I'm getting : `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://infoportal.vag.de/InfoPortal/busstations.xhr' from origin 'http://localhost' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.` Although he may not have the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code should work  (but not within this snippet)

```js
const
  Limit        = 20,
  LoadingTable = document.getElementById('Loading-Table')
  ;

let xdr = getXDomainRequest("get", "http://infoportal.vag.de/InfoPortal/busstations.xhr");

if (!xdr) {
  throw new Error("no cross-domain allowed by your browser :/");
};

xdr.onload = function() {
  jsonData = JSON.parse(xdr.responseText);
  let line = 0;
  for (elm in jsonData) {
    let
      row = LoadingTable.insertRow(line),
      c_0 = row.insertCell(0),
      c_1 = row.insertCell(1),
      c_2 = row.insertCell(2),
      c_3 = row.insertCell(3)
      ;
    c_0.textContent = elm;
    c_1.textContent = jsonData[elm].name;
    c_2.textContent = jsonData[elm].x;
    c_3.textContent = jsonData[elm].y;

    if (++line >= Limit) break;
  }
}

xdr.send();


function getXDomainRequest( method, url ) {
  var xdr = null;

  if (window.XDomainRequest) {  // MS ie
    xdr = new XDomainRequest(); 
    xhr.open(method, url);
  }
  else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xdr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    if ('withCredentials' in xdr) {
      xdr.open(method, url, true);
    }
    else {
      xdr = null;
    }
  } 
  return xdr; 
}
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#Loading-Table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#Loading-Table, 
#Loading-Table td {
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
#Loading-Table td {
  padding: 2px 10px;
}
```

```html
<h2>Make a table based on JSON data.</h2>
<p id="demo"></p>

<table id="Loading-Table" ></table>
```